# Looking for a 1970s/80s children's book about pirates in space

Tags: story-identification, space, childrens-novel, pirates

The characters were white, (I don't mean white as in Caucasian, I mean white as in a Casper the friendly ghost or a Moomin or something) cartoon-like things, there was a big floating pirate ship, and there was a page where one of the white characters walked the plank. I would think it was no more than 20 pages long.

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: I thought it might be Matthew Looney and the Space Pirates by Jerome Beatty because the characters were white Moomin-like things. But flipping through it I found zero illustrations of somebody walking the plank.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Captain Harlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Harlock) ?
The character was created by Leiji Matsumoto in 1977 and popularized in the 1978 television series Space Pirate Captain Harlock.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, when I say white, I don't mean white as in Caucasian, I mean white as in a Casper the friendly ghost or a Moomin or something.  I don't think I ever saw it on TV, just in the book format.  Thanks for the reply nonetheless though.